# Template helper based on session, fail to update

Tags: javascript, css, meteor

This Meteor client code receives user input `keyup .check-filter` and changes the array of objects in a session `itemsList`, which is used to supply the template helper with its data.
The code changes the data which goes to `{{this.class}}` which matches a css class to style the list item.
When the code adds the class to the data in the session, the browser responds OK. And if the code removes the class from said data, the browser responds OK, but when the class is added to the same item again, the browser does not respond by adding the class even though the underlaying data is present as inspected by the console log.
I know the browser did not add the class after checking the browser element tab.

However when the code adds the class to another item then removes it and adds a class to the first item which did not work before, then the first item works again.

Any idea why this is happening and how to fix it? Thanks

```
Template.checks.helpers({
  'values': function() {
    let result = [];
    let checks = Session.get('itemsList'); //<--- array of objects
    checks.forEach((item) => {
      if (some condition) {
        result.push({
          label: item.name,
          class: item.class,
          key: item.key,
          image: utility.getUrlForImageLabel(item.name)
        });
      } else {
        result.push({
          label: item.name,
          class: item.class,
          image: utility.getUrlForImageLabel(item.name)
        });
      }
    });
    console.log(result); //<--- confirms data inclusion.
    return result;
  }
});

Template.checks.events({
  'keyup .check-filter': function(event) {

    //build the array of objects and stores in the session 'itemsList'
    utility.checksFiltering(event.target.value);
  }
});
```

```html
<template name="checks">
  <form>
    <div class="list-item">
      <input class="check-filter" type="text" placeholder="Start typing, fast find">
    </div>

    <div class="list-item">
      {{#each values}}
      <ul class="checks-row" data-key={{this.key}}>
        <li class="check-image {{this.image}}">
          <img src="/{{this.image}}">
        </li>
        <li class="check-label {{this.class}}">{{this.label}}</li> //<------ problem element
      </ul>
      {{/each}}
    </div>
  </form>
</template>
```